# Update list with function (without return value)

Tags: c, list

I have a list like this:

```
typedef struct list {
     char *key;
     char *value;
     struct list *next;
} List;
```

And using it in my main function:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    List *list;
    list = malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    list = insertToList("key", "value", list);
}
```

The insertToList is:

```
List insertToList(char *key, char *value, List *list) {
    List *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    newNode->key = malloc(strlen(key));
    strcpy(newNode->key, key);

    newNode->value = malloc(strlen(value));
    strcpy(newNode->value, value);
    newNode->next = list;
    list = newNode;

    return list;
}
```

This works as expected, but I would like to modify the list by using pointer instead, so that I do not have to return the list. I tried to pass the &list as argument to insertToList and then recieve it with **list in, but that did not work. How do I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "that did not work" for the **list? What happened when you tried that approach?

Comment: your `newNode->key = malloc(strlen(key)); strcpy(newNode->key, key);` is broken and can cause an overflow because you do not allocate space for trailing `'\0'`.  Use `newNode->key = strdup(key)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What basically is needed, is a pointer to a pointer: `List**`:

```
void insertToList(char *key, char *value, List** list) {
    List *newNode = malloc(sizeof(List));
    newNode->key = malloc(strlen(key));
    strcpy(newNode->key, key);

    newNode->value = malloc(strlen(value));
    strcpy(newNode->value, value);
    newNode->next = *list;
    *list = newNode;
}
```

Rename `List` to `ListNode` for more clarity

An alternative is, to define an extra structure `List` to wrap the 'head pointer' (`ListNode*`). This structure could contain additional values, such as the current list size.

```
typedef struct ListNode
{
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct ListNode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct List
{
    struct ListNode* head;
} List;

void insertAtFront(char *key, char *value, List* list)
{
    ListNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(List));
    newNode->key = malloc(strlen(key));
    strcpy(newNode->key, key);

    newNode->value = malloc(strlen(value));
    strcpy(newNode->value, value);
    newNode->next = list->head;
    list->head = newNode;
}

void insertBefore(char *key, char *value, ListNode** listNode)
{
    ListNode* newNode = malloc(sizeof(List));
    newNode->key = malloc(strlen(key));
    strcpy(newNode->key, key);

    newNode->value = malloc(strlen(value));
    strcpy(newNode->value, value);
    newNode->next = *listNode;
    *listNode = newNode;
}
```

Comment: Do I have to send the &list to the function then?

Answer (score 0):

Your first thought of using a List** is probably the best one, but this would work to. Your last node in the list doesn't contain any data, since you malloc'd it in main and didn't fill it up. You could insert all new nodes after that first one, then you don't need to return the list pointer, since it is not changing. So, in insertToList, you could insert the newNode with:

```
newNode->next = list->next;
list->next = newNode;
```

The downside of this is that your first node is wasted space, but the way you had it, the last node was wasted space anyway, we're just moving it.